# Update sql table with parameters not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this method in an asp page, there are no errors when executed but even no updates. 
What am I doing wrong in this method that does not update the table?

```
protected void saveSettings()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sendyourmessageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string userName = "something";

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Tb_Registration SET Country = @Country, City = @City Where Username = @Username" , con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value=userName;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@Country"].Value= txtCountry.Text.Trim();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@City"].Value= txtCity.Text.Trim();

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Your settings have been saved');", true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have user called something in your database?

Comment: @danish, yes, I am testing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is `AddWithValue` method.

It takes the parameter value as a second parameter, not `SqlDbType`.

But don't use this method anymore. It *might* generate unexpected results. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it's overloads.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Tb_Registration SET Country = @Country, City = @City
                       Where Username = @Username";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCountry.Text.Trim();
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text.Trim();
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar);`

It should be value of parameter, not type if you're using `AddWithValue`

But better practice - not to use `AddWithValue` at all, as it can lead to different problems.

Instead use something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert direct values rather that providing datatype

```
 protected void saveSettings()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sendyourmessageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string userName = "something";

            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Tb_Registration SET Country = @Country, City = @City Where Username = @Username" , con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName);


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country",  txtCountry.Text.Trim());


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text.Trim());


                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Your settings have been saved');", true);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to AddWithValue is your value not the sql type

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName);
```